# d3: update data appended on elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a graph with a line, two areas and a few circles in it: [image: the graph]

I wrote an update method, which works just fine for everything except the circles:

```
function updateGraph() {
  xScale.domain([startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime()]);
  addTimedTickPadding(xAxis);
  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(interpolatedData, function (d) {
    return d.y0 + d.y1;
  })]);
  var updateGroup = parentGroup.transition();
  updateGroup.select('.xaxis')
    .duration(750)
    .call(xAxis);
  updateGroup.select('.yxaxis')
    .duration(750)
    .call(yAxis);
  updateGroup.select('.xgrid')
    .duration(750)
    .call(verticalGridLine());
  updateGroup.select('.area-top')
    .duration(750)
    .attr('d', areaTop(interpolatedData));
  updateGroup.select('.area-bottom')
    .duration(750)
    .attr('d', areaBottom(interpolatedData));
  updateGroup.select('.line')
    .duration(750)
    .attr('d', line(interpolatedData));
  updateGroup.select('.post')
    .duration(750)
    .data(interpolatedData)
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
      return xScale(dateParser.parse(d.x))
    })
    .attr('cy', function (d) {
      return yScale(d.y0 + d.y1)
    });
}
```

Everything transitions as expected but the circles. They just stay in place. My thought was: I append the updated data to each element and alter the cx and cy attributes accordingly, so the circles transition to their new place. But they don't move :( What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the initial code for the circles:

```
dataGroup
    .selectAll('.post')
    .data(interpolatedData)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .classed('post', true)
    .attr({
      'r': circleRadius,
      'fill': circleFillColor,
      'stroke-width': circleStrokeWidth,
      'stroke': circleStrokeColor,
      'cx': (function (d) {
        return xScale(dateParser.parse(d.x))
      }),
      'cy': (function (d) {
        return yScale(d.y0 + d.y1)
      })
    });
```

PS: I read abaout enter() and exit() [here](https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36#.psp08l7qi) but don't really know, how they could be useful for updating the data which is appended on the elements.

PPS: I tried selectAll() too, but it doesn't seem to have a data() function.

Comment: looks like you're re-appending the data to the circles /after/ calling their transition - do you have a jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: Not yet, I will make one and append it.

Comment: My fiddle doesn't really work, but here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/rr01ut3x/ - what do you mean by 'reappending data after calling transition'? I try to update the data that is appended onto the circles, so they move to the point of the "new" data.